# Applying Bayes' rule to get the posterior

Tags: probability, bayesian

$f(\cdot)$ is a three dimensional probability distribution function. The posterior is obtained by
$$
f(\mu | R, \theta) \propto f(R, \theta | \mu) f(\mu)
$$
But from here, it is expanded as
$$
= f(R|\theta, \mu) f(\theta | \mu) f(\mu)
$$

$\frac{f(R,\theta| \mu) }{f(\theta| \mu)} = f(R| \theta, \mu)$, so $f(R,\theta| \mu)  = f(R| \theta, \mu) f(\theta| \mu)$ is being used here, it seems. But why does this work? Are we allowed to do treat $f(\cdot)$ conditioned on $\mu$ the same as if it is not conditioned on anything?

Can anyone provide an intuitive explanation of what is going on here?

Comment: If you treat $\mu$ as fixed, $f(R,\theta| \mu)  = f(R| \theta, \mu) f(\theta| \mu)$ is a generic decomposition of the joint density of $(R,\theta)$ as a marginal times a conditional.

Comment: So, would it be okay if I interpret this as $f(R, \theta | \mu) = f(R, \theta) P(\mu = \mu_0)$ so that it would lead to the decomposition $f(R, \theta)  = f(R|\theta)f(\theta)$?

Comment: no this is not equivalent. Treat $\mu$ as fixed, ie write $$f(R,\theta| \mu)  = f_\mu(R,\theta) = f_\mu(R| \theta) f_\mu(\theta)$$